# Is there a working example of Slick 2.0 AutoInc with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, slick

I am relatively new to Slick and I keep getting the *org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint* message.

I found plenty of examples with Slick 1.x but none of them seem to work with Slick 2.0
Can someone point to a working example with Slick 2.x (I have 2.0.1) and Postgres?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the example. I did fix my problem.
The hint came from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718585/set-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql) .

In my original table, the primary key was `integer`.

I had to change it to `serial`.

Now, things work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Slick-2.0.1 example with  postgreSQL database : 
 https://github.com/satendrakumar06/slickwithpostgresql