# Seeds.rb sets primary key value, results in duplicate key error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

In my Rails 4 app, which I am using on Heroku for production, I have set up a seeds.rb file for the initial set of data. As it is critical that a few records have specific primary ids, say in the 'activities' table, I have set those. All goes well.

UNTIL. Until I need to add a new activity to the activities table. Adding a new record will fail as many times as there are records in that table, while the sequencer catches up. (e.g. if I have three records, new record creation fails three times, succeeds on the fourth).

QUESTION: How can I get the primary ID counter on the Heroku postgres database to start after the highest primary id set in my seeds.rb file? If you don't know, what terms should I be googling?

Ideally, this solution would be automatic, and not something I have to open psql for each time I seed the database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The :id column is an auto-increment column. As such, you don't have control over what value it uses -- it just always uses the next id available in its internal counter. If this were me I'd find some other way to identify those few records than by :id. For example, maybe you can refer to the records by a :name or some other special attribute? (Don't forget to index the attribute you're finding by if you do go this route!)

Then, I'd use the [seed_fu gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) to perform idempotent seeding, as you seem to be wanting. With idempotent seeding, if a record exists already then it will be updated (if there are any updates to be performed; if not then it's a no-op). This way you don't have exceptions and you can always add new or update existing records.

Comment: You wrote 
> it just always uses the next id available in its internal counter 
Question is, how do I force postgres or rails to use the next value after the highest primary key value, instead of using it's own counter?

Answer (score 1):

**Auto Increment**

Further to `pdobb`'s answer, you'll benefit from reading up about [`auto_increment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718585/set-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql) - when you insert data into a table with `auto_increment` columns, it will just add a number to the end of the last one. In *normal* circumstances, you don't have to be concerned with it at all

If you need to include items in particular `ids`, such as if you're referencing a specific record or something, my best advice is to change your system to not deal with specific `primary_keys`

--

**Example**

We use an `options` table with the `CMS` we created, and reference `role_id`'s from the `options` table (which we seed):

[image]

This is populated from our `db/seeds.rb` file:

```
Option.create({name: "role", value: "admin"})
Option.create({name: "role", value: "moderator"})
Option.create({name: "role", value: "author"})
```

Notice no reference to `id`?

This means we can reference the `role` as follows:

```
#app/models/profile.rb
belongs_to :role, -> { where(name: "role") }, class_name: "Option", foreign_key: "role"

def role
  role_name = Option.find self[:role]
  role_name.value
end
```

So we store the `role` `id` in our `role` column; and access that with a custom `instance method` which overrides the getter made by Rails!

So if I call

```
current_user.profile.role # -> in DB, will have id stored, but will output "value" of that
```

--

This means we're able to assign an `id` automatically!

This works because even if you remove the preceding items, the `id` of the `role` records will still remain the same. You don't need to worry about your `auto_increment` column

Comment: I'm very intrigued but I don't quite get what the conclusion is here. I don't understand the Profile/Option relationship... namely the `foreign_key` option and how this implies being able to "assign an `id` automatically." I get that... Profile points to a role which comes from the Option class scoped by a `name` of `"role"`. But then what? Is there a Role model still that this reference somehow alludes to?

Comment: Is there a *profiles.role* column which contains one of `%w[admin moderator author]`? But then... what? You still have an Option object as your "role" as a Profile, right?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put in the rest (it's some cool coding wizardry we did)

Comment: Updated for you dear sir

Comment: Thanks, @Rich! Still trying to figure it out, though. So you said "which overrides the **setter** made by Rails" -- do you mean **getter**? Given the `role` method you've defined, what's the point of the `belongs_to`? Does the `belongs_to` interact with your custom `role` method due to the `:foreign_key` option having the same name? Or is the `belongs_to` just used as a setter? And finally, is there a _Role_ model or no? (Is the role just a string value in the end?)

Comment: LOL sorry, I actually need to work out the difference. You're right - the **getter** (blushes)

Comment: Sorry, another oversight of mine. We have an `Option` model (works exactly the same as `wp_options` in Wordpress), and we store the `roles` in there.

Comment: So the user's `profile` `belongs_to :role`; but `role` is inside `Option`. We use the custom method to take the `value` option of the `Option` record & output that instead

Comment: No role model - the `Option` model acts as the model for it. The reason I used this example is because we use another model for an association, and rely on the `id` (`primary_key`) staying intact. I'm trying to demonstrate *why* you don't need to worry about setting the `primary_key` with `auto_increment`

Comment: You sure? If you need any more clarification, just ask1

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with the acts_as_taggable_on gem for rails when it would throw duplicate tag error.

After I `rails db:seed` I run `RAILS_ENV=development rake db:reset_pk_sequence` so that the keys are reset.

```
# lib/tasks/tag_cleaner.rake
# run using 'RAILS_ENV=development rake db:reset_pk_sequence'

namespace :db do
  desc "reset the pk sequence"
  task :reset_pk_sequence => :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |t|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(t)
    end
  end
end
```

This seems to fix it but then I haven't tried in production as I don't use seed data for production.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that I was running seeds.rb from

```
$ rake db:setup
```

db:setup recreates the database, and thus resets the counter. By switching to:

```
$ rake db:migrate
$ rake db:seed
```

I am able to modify my seed data in the production database without resetting the Postgres primary ID counter.

On a side note, so that this never happens accidentally, I have also created a rakefile that raises an error when rake db:setup is entered.